# Webdriver test pause unexpectedly

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a `Selenium WebDriver` based testcase, which pauses during execution. It should upload thousands of files to a website. When it chooses the file to upload it sometimes doesn't click ok, but waits for manual interaction. In most cases it is working perfectly.
I use `StringSelection` to copy and paste file source to input field.

```
StringSelection cp = new StringSelection(fileSource);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(cp, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test could be running to quickly? If this is the case, then you could potentially use WebDriverWait?? WebDriverWait could be used to wait for the 'OK' element to be visible prior to clicking and therefore proceeding.

I might be wrong, but I can't really tell what the issue is without the rest of the code.

Personally, I use the following method which I can then call

```
public void waitForElementToBeVisible(String cssSelector) throws Throwable {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssSelector))
        ));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Timeout exceeded");
        closeDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know `WebDriverWait`, but don't know how to specify ok button in `presenceOfElementLocated()` method.

Comment: presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("test")) does that help? Updated the answer too for what I use within my test cases. If this doesn't help, please let me know and I'll delete the answer rather than it getting down voted!

Comment: How could I identify the OK button in the file chooser window?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("id of ok button")).click(); if by identify you mean click?

Comment: I don't know this id, because I can't get it from browser.

Comment: Can you paste the html of the 'ok' button? Does is have a class or anything??

Comment: This button is from the browser, not on web application level.

Answer (score 1):

For behavior "When it chooses the file to upload it sometimes doesn't click ok, but waits for manual interaction. In most cases it is working perfectly." I prefer use failed retry count. Every step with click should be wrapped up on the test and if test result=failed - retry test some times(3 or 5). JUnit have good mechanizm for that:

```
    @RunWith(Runner.class)
    public abstract class AbstractTest extends LibTest {
        @Rule
        public JUnitRetry retry = new JUnitRetry(3);
    }

    public class Test extends AbstractTest
        @Test
        public void testCp(String fileSource){
            StringSelection cp = new StringSelection(fileSource);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(cp, null);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code working fine for the similar scenario in our environment.

```
StringSelection cp = new StringSelection(fileSource);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(cp, null);
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

We can also use AutoIT to perform this type actions.

Please find AutoIT code to handle this case.

Download AutoIT ,write this code in AutoIT name it as 'Loadfromdisk' and compile. .exe will be generated, please place exe somwhere in your local drive(ex: E:\Loadfromdisk.exe)

```
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","2") ;
$title=WinGetTitle("[CLASS:DirectUIHWND; INSTANCE:2]")
WinActivate($title)
WinWaitActive($title)
If WinExists($title) Then
    WinFlash($title,"", 4, 500) ;Just to Flash the window
EndIf
Sleep(1000)
ControlSetText($title, "", "Edit1", fileSource)
Sleep(1000)
ControlClick($title,"","Button1")
Exit
```

Load from disk Selenium Java code, this will load the file placed at 'filesource' path mentioned in AutoIT code into web application

```
String strAutoIT = "E:\\Loadfromdisk.exe";
Thread.sleep(3000);
String[] astrArg = null;
astrArg=new String[]{strAutoIT};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(astrArg);
```

Please see whether this helps to run your testcase.

Comment: I use the exact same solution at this time. :)

Comment: It is the problem here, because I think, it causes that the test sometimes stopes.

Comment: I've added AutoIT code to verify same test case, please see.